# Uniswapv2 addLiquidity Decimal error in Remix (Bignumber)

Tags: solidity

I'm testing Uniswapv2 for a project and am getting this error:

```
transact to UniswapV2Router02.addLiquidity errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid BigNumber string (argument="value", value=".004", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.1.1)
```

The Uniswapv2 code is normal and unedited. I tested these number on Uniswap itself to make sure the numbers worked before I tried them in Remix. These are what I tried to pass:

```
tokenA: 0xc778417e063141139fce010982780140aa0cd5ab (WETH since I can't find ETH address)
tokenB: 0x1f9840a85d5af5bf1d1762f925bdaddc4201f984 (UNI)
amountADesired: 0.004
amountBDesired: 0.03
amountAMin:1
amountBMin:2
to: 0xd50eCE9501a1f63e449DbBBbBdc5CB59f3e2c231
deadline: 255
```

Answer (score 0):

Solidity contracts don't take decimal arguments. Instead, you need to pass the amount of smallest units.

[WETH](https://etherscan.io/token/0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2) (note - you have an **incorrect address** in your question) has 18 decimals, [UNI](https://etherscan.io/token/0x1f9840a85d5af5bf1d1762f925bdaddc4201f984) has 18 as well.

---

1 WETH is 1000000000000000000 (or 10^18) units.

So if you want to pass 0.004 WETH in the argument, you need to input the number **4000000000000000** (which is 0.004 * 10^18).

---

Note: ETH is the native currency of the Ethereum network, so there is no token address for ETH. [Uniswap v2 Router 2](https://etherscan.io/address/0x7a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d) has a function `addLiquidityETH()` for when you want to add liquidity to a pair of a token to ETH.

Comment: Ok, I didn't realize I had to pass it with the decimal amount included so that makes sense. And I didn't even think to test with addLiquidityETH so I appreciate it.

Comment: I tried passing them like that but I'm getting a Gas Estimation Error. I tried increasing gas paid to 70(0.2 ETH) manually on Metamask but it didn't help. Does the router contract need to hold ETH or am I missing something?

Comment: Gas estimation error usually happens when the transaction fails a `revert` or an `assert` condition and throws an uncaught exception. This is a general error and is hard to troubleshoot, but check whether you have enough tokens, whether the deadline is correctly set (I'm just guessing that it might need to be a unix timestamp, not a number of seconds from now), ... generally check your inputs.